# Kendo UI grid not triggering transport create URL

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Ive a kendoUI grid doing CRUD from a web service. For some reason, read command works perfectly and populates my grid.

But when I try to create a new record, despite that it shows the new record in the grid and i can edit its fields, button save does not trigger the web service.

Checking out http logs, I see no hit on the service. Only on "read".

This is the grid's code:

```
$(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: "libyMsg.php?way=getUsrMsgList"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "libyMsg.php?way=createMsg",
                        type: "PUT"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: "libyMsg.php?way=updateeMsg",
                        type: "PUT"
                    },destroy: {
                        url: "libyMsg.php?way=destroyMsg",
                        type: "PUT"
                    },
                    batch: true,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    schema: {
                        data: "data",
                        model: {
                            id: "msg_id",
                            fields: {
                                msg_id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                msg_title: { validation: { required: true } },
                                msg_content: {  validation: { required: true } },
                                msg_type: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true }},
                                msg_date: { type: "date", validation: { required: true } },
                                msg_status: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                columns: [{ field: "msg_id", width: 40,title: "ID" },
                    { field: "msg_title",width: 300, title: "Title" },
                    { field: "msg_content", width: 300,title: "Content" },
                    { field: "msg_type", width: 40,title: "Type" },
                    { field: "msg_date", width: 300,title: "Date" }, 
                    { field: "msg_status", width: 40,title: "Status" }],
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                editable:true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true
                },
                toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            });
        });
```

This is driving me crazy. Anyone?

Ty/M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `transport` is wrong. Try this instead:

```
transport:{
    read      :"libyMsg.php?way=getUsrMsgList",
    create    :{
        url :"libyMsg.php?way=createMsg",
        type:"PUT"
    },
    update    :{
        url :"libyMsg.php?way=updateeMsg",
        type:"PUT"
    },
    destroy:{
        url :"libyMsg.php?way=destroyMsg",
        type:"PUT"
    }
},
```

`create`, `update` and `destroy` should be part of `transport`.